# Selenium web driver if style height 0

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to have a selenium webdriver script do something if the height of a style is 0. I am able to print it using the element.value_of_css_property command but I want to use it as an if statement. So it would be.

If value of height = 0px do one thing. If the value of the height is anything else do the other.  Here is the HTML code I am working with.

```
<div id="computerfilter" class="gridView safari fixed" style="min-width: 110px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 89%;">
 <ul style="position: relative; list-style: none; padding-inline-start: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; height: 0px; width: 1000px;"><div style="position: relative; top: 0px;" class="viewport"><li class="lmigrid-row parent expanded" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

I have tried the following code but Its not working

```
if len(self.driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul.computerfilter[style height:0px]"))
```

Comment: I see 2 asterisk(*) around `height: 0px` in the HTML. Is that how it is in the actual HTML DOM?

Comment: I was trying to bold the text to show that's the element that I am trying to pull but for some reason it put two ** instead of bolding. I have removed them now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Try either this code:**

   ```
   element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='computerfilter']").get_attribute("innerHTML")
   print(element)

   if "height: 0px" in element:
       print("height is 0")
   else:
       print("height is not 0")
   ```
2. **Or try this:**

   ```
   element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@id='computerfilter']/ul").get_attribute("style")
   print(element)

   if "height: 0px" in element:
       print("height is 0")
   else:
       print("height is not 0")
   ```

**Console output:**

```
height is 0
```